# Delayed Branch response iOS after App Store Install

Tags: ios, swift, branch, branch.io, ios-universal-links

Hie 
I have a webpage which redirect the user to my app using **Branch's Universal Links**. If the app is not installed in the phone, the user is redirected to AppStore; else the app opens. 
I use Branch to send some keys along with it to the app. As soon as the app opens, the branch's callback block in app receives a response and the keys are received in the app.
But sometimes, branch's response is delayed and keys recieval is delayed. The keys being sent are required on immediately as soon as the app launch ends.

Can I do something to **minimise this lag time from branch's response**.

the time lag occurs randomly - once in 8 times.

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
     Branch.getInstance().initSession(launchOptions: launchOptions) { params, error in
            // params are the deep linked params associated with the link that the user clicked -> was re-directed to this app
            // params will be empty if no data found

            if error == nil {
                print(params as? [String: AnyObject] ?? {})

                            }
                        }
                    }
}
```

This block receives a call back when branch sends keys/parameters. Sometimes this block is called after 2-5 minutes after app has been launched.

Comment: post the code and mention where exact u got struck

Comment: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to write a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @NitinSingh Branch is working perfectly fine. Universal linking is performed and keys are received in app as well. But sometimes, the app recieves the keys after like a time lag of 2-3 minutes or sometimes 5 minutes.

Comment: @NitinSingh code added.

Answer (score 0):

Jackie from Branch here. All our services are operational with no significant latency that you can expect. (Refer to our status page here: https://status.branch.io/)

If you continue to experience delays in a consistent manner, can you try running our sample code and see if the behavior repeats itself? (please be sure to test on a strong wifi to rule out any network issues!)
https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/#install-branch

Feel free to reach out to us directly at integration@branch.io if you have any further questions. You can include your Branch credentials in the email for our team to do a personalized investigation!